# unable to group by category and unixtime desc

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bb44/1

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
userid int(255),
 category int(255),
  unixtime int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (userid,category,unixtime) VALUES
('1', '1','1438689946'),
('1', '2','1438690005'),
('1', '3','1438690007'),
('5', '1','1438690009'),
('2', '1','1438690005'),
('2', '1','1438690398'),
('1', '2','1438691020'),
('1', '3','1438691028'),
('4', '2','1438690005'),
('2', '3','1438691025'),
('2', '2','1438691020'),
('3', '3','1438691022');
```

and

```
Select * from tblA  group by category order by unixtime  desc;
```

But I am getting wrong values.The values do not contain right unixtime desc.How can I make it work ? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Group by without aggregate function ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty  How to group by aggregate ?

Comment: @jason what exactly do you want to return as a result ?

Comment: Did you mean this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bb44/3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query . If 2 unixtime are same this should display only 1

```
Select a.*
from tblA a join
     (select category, max(unixtime) as maxut
      from tblA
      group by category
     ) c
     on a.category = c.category and a.unixtime = c.maxut
group by unixtime order by a.unixtime desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot express what you want in the way you have done it.  The `order by` is processed *after* the `group by`.  Presumably you want:

```
Select a.*
from tblA a join
     (select category, max(unixtime) as maxut
      from tblA
      group by category
     ) c
     on a.category = c.category and a.unixtime = c.maxut
order by a.unixtime desc;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon . If 2 unixtime  are same for a category it displays both.How can I display only 1? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/708622/1 .Thanks

Comment: @jason  . . . If that is an issue, I would suggest that you just use the `id` column instead.